# Compare each row to one another on the basis of first three columns and output only one line

Tags: unix, awk

I have file like this

chr1    13369510    13369602    PRAMEF18    0   +

chr1    13369510    13369602    PRAMEF19    0   +

i want to compare first three columns of every row and if it matches then i want an output like this

chr1    13369510    13369602    PRAMEF18,PRAMEF19  0    +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
 awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
      {
        key = $1 FS $2 FS $3;
        last_fields[key] = $5 FS $6;
        lines[key] = lines[key]?lines[key] ", " $4 : $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4;
      }
      END {
        for (line in lines) print lines[line], last_fields[line]
      }' your_file.tsv
```

- First use column 1, 2 and 3 as a key.
- Create a dict with all the lines of the files, using col1,2,3 as key. If the key already exists in the dict, append the 4th column (the one you want to merge).
- Print

(Edited the code following Ed Morton's advice)

Comment: previous code was working well...this one throws error

Comment: @sawasthi Sorry, could you try it now?, I added by mistake an additional "{" :)

Comment: again showing error

Comment: @sawasthi "showing error" is the worst possible problem statement as it tells us absolutely nothing that could be used to diagnose the problem. It's like dropping your car off at the mechanic and just saying "it doesn't work" and then expecting them to fix it. When telling anyone about any problem you want help with, in software or in life, you've got to tell them **something** about the problem. In this case tell us the error messages, or if there's wrong output, no output, or something else?

Comment: Sir, with all due respect the very first code and the the above mentioned code are working well for my problem. Earlier it was throwing an error of  "{" but i have rerun the code again now and its working fine.Thanks for the help